# Programmatically reorder or move elements in Draggable + Packery (Masonry)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable, masonry, packery

Here's a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/00uvL60c/1/

When i press "move left" / "move right" I want to send the block left/right. I do this by reinserting it on the dom structure with `el.insertBefore(el.prev())` / `el.insertAfter(el.next())` but this don't work since it keeps the `left` / `top` coordinates, and also don't touch the packery inner structure, if there's any.

If I drag the block it works. On bottom right i display the result of `packery('getItemElements')` but this is read only.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked a but with isotope (something similar).

Now the direct answer http://jsfiddle.net/yry6kknh/:

```
$(".item .left").on("click", function() {
  var el = $(this).closest(".item");
      if (el.prev()) {
        el.insertBefore(el.prev());
         $("#cont").packery('reloadItems');
         $("#cont").packery();
      }    
});

$(".item .right").on("click", function() {
  var el = $(this).closest(".item");
      if (el.next()) {
        el.insertAfter(el.next());
        $("#cont").packery('reloadItems');
        $("#cont").packery();
      }    
});
```

First fix: use  $("#cont") instead of scope variable $container, to have all the time the last DOM elements (lazy loading or another DOM operations)

Second I checked http://packery.metafizzy.co/js/packery-docs.min.js and found packery.prototype.reloadItems, when html is changed, packery needs to update his items, and $("#cont").packery(); to force re rendering.

This is not the most correct method, but is working :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. It works fine with `$container.packery('reloadItems').packery();`

Answer (score 2):

Hi you may use this [https://jsfiddle.net/ibad_gore/00uvL60c/28](http://jsfiddle.net/ibad_gore/00uvL60c/28/)

My changes in your code are :

```
$(".item .left").on("click", function(event) {
              var ch = $(this).closest('.item');
              $container.packery( 'fit', ch[0] , 202, ch.offset().top )
});

$(".item .right").on("click", function(event) {
              var ch = $(this).closest('.item');
              $container.packery( 'fit', ch[0] , 0, ch.offset().top )
});
```

You may manage the value 0 and 202 as per requirements.

Comment: thanks but the elements may have variable size. SilentTremor answer did it.